# When i added C++ code in win32_window.cpp file ,application can not run

Tags: c++, flutter, winapi

I want to create an application locked to the desktop using flutter. Make it look integrated with the windows desktop.

So I found some methods on the Internet, which instructed me to just add the following code to flutter's win32 file code. But it actually doesn't work after I add it. There aren't even any errors.

I have defined the CheckParent function in the win32_window.h file. When I add the code in win32_window.cpp, the code cannot run.

win32_window.h

```
bool CheckParent(HWND hWnd);
```

win32_window.cpp

```cpp
bool Win32Window::CheckParent(HWND hWnd){
   HWND s_hWndOldParent;
   HWND hWndProgram;
   HWND hWndShellDLL;
   hWndProgram = FindWindow(TEXT("Progman"), TEXT("Program Manager"));
   if(hWndProgram != NULL)
   {
       hWndShellDLL = FindWindowEx(hWndProgram, NULL, TEXT("SHELLDLL_DefView"), NULL);
   }

   if(hWndShellDLL != NULL
       && hWndShellDLL != s_hWndOldParent)
   {  
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, 0, (LONG)hWndShellDLL);
        s_hWndOldParent = hWndShellDLL;
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

```cpp
 HWND window = CreateWindow(
      window_class, title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      Scale(origin.x, scale_factor), Scale(origin.y, scale_factor),
      Scale(size.width, scale_factor), Scale(size.height, scale_factor),
      nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);
  
/// this code is added in  the CreateWindow Function
CheckParent(window);

  SetWindowPos(window, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0,SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

There is no problem error message in the flutter program here.

thanks!

I have made many attempts, such as clearing the code in the CheckParent function and leaving only return false, and the code can run. If any other code is added to this function, the program will not start normally.

I hope you can help me tell me why this code cannot run? Or help me correct it so that it can run correctly

Comment: There is no way to do what you're trying to do. This is not supported by the OS.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what "Make it look integrated with the windows desktop" means, but a couple of obvious problems: `s_hWndOldParent` is not initialized before checking `hWndShellDLL != s_hWndOldParen`, which is undefined behavior.  Similarly, `hWndShellDLL` is not necessarily initialized before checking it.  You should be using [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) instead of `SetWindowLong`, although [`HWND`s use only 32 bits for compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1822667/), so that's probably ok.

Comment: I mean it looks like it's not really embedded in the desktop. In other words, it will always be displayed on the desktop, even if you press Window+D. Unless you turn it off. Similar to the sidebar of Windows 7。

Comment: *"But it actually doesn't work after I add it. There aren't even any errors."* This is contradictory. Not working **is** an error. Perhaps you meant that there are no errors (usually syntax errors) reported during compilation?